# Adwords API UserListService results in attribute error on calling mutate

Tags: python-2.7, api, google-ads-api, google-api-python-client

I am Adding a new User List using Google AdWords API userListService,I have passed all the required inputs and the adword client instance got created successfully.

But while calling the mutate method it is throwing an attribute error
"AttributeError: class HttpTransport has no attribute '_HttpTransport__get_request_url'"

**Please find the StackTrace:**

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 5\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 2411, in 
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 5\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1802, in run
    launch(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script

File "D:/Python Studies/SVN Code/Work In Progress/Source Code/doubleclick-Dmp-Integration/DmpIntegrationApplication/dmpintegration/dmpex/adwords.py", line 93, in 
    main(adwords_client)

File "D:/Python Studies/SVN Code/Work In Progress/Source Code/doubleclick-Dmp-Integration/DmpIntegrationApplication/dmpintegration/dmpex/adwords.py", line 33, in main
    result = user_list_service.mutate(operations)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\googleads\common.py", line 720, in MakeSoapRequest
    *[_PackForSuds(arg, self.suds_client.factory) for arg in args])

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\suds\client.py", line 542, in **call**
    return client.invoke(args, kwargs)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\suds\client.py", line 602, in invoke
    result = self.send(soapenv)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\suds\client.py", line 637, in send
    reply = transport.send(request)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\googleads\util.py", line 92, in PatchedHttpTransportSend
    url = http_transport._HttpTransport__get_request_url(request)

AttributeError: class HttpTransport has no attribute '_HttpTransport__get_request_url'

**Here is my code:**

```
import uuid
from googleads import adwords
from googleads import oauth2

def main(client):
    # Initialize appropriate service.
    user_list_service = client.GetService(
        'AdwordsUserListService', version='v201702')

    # Construct operations and add a user list.
    operations = [
    {
        'operator': 'ADD',
        'operand': {
            'xsi_type': 'BasicUserList',
            'name': 'Mars cruise customers #%s' % uuid.uuid4(),
            'description': 'A list of mars cruise customers in the last 
    year',
            'membershipLifeSpan': '365',
            'conversionTypes': [
                {
                    'name': ('Mars cruise customers #%s'
                             % uuid.uuid4())
                }
            ],
            # Optional field.
            'status': 'OPEN',
            }
        }
    ]
    result = user_list_service.mutate(operations)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    CLIENT_ID = 'xxx'
    CLIENT_SECRET = 'xxx'
    REFRESH_TOKEN = 'xxx'
    DEVELOPER_TOKEN = 'xxx'
    USER_AGENT = 'xxx'
    CLIENT_CUSTOMER_ID = 'xxx'
    oauth2_client = oauth2.GoogleRefreshTokenClient(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, REFRESH_TOKEN)
    adwords_client = adwords.AdWordsClient(DEVELOPER_TOKEN, oauth2_client, USER_AGENT,client_customer_id=CLIENT_CUSTOMER_ID)
    main(adwords_client)
```